# How to post images to Azure storage in powerapps?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, powerapps

I have a collection of images in Powerapps, that I want to send to Azure storage so that I can access them in the Azure function.

I have tried to create a workflow in PowerApps using Create block blob, but I cant use dynamic content in there.

So How can I send all the images I have in a collection to Azure storage?

I am doing this, so I can have access to these images within the function. If there is an alternative way, I can try that too. I just need access to them in Azure function.

Comment: I have had similar issues to this in the past. When an image is sent from PowerApps it is sent as a Base64 string. What you could possibly try is to send the images(Base64) to an Azure Storage Table as an entity, then inside your function retrieve the entity with the Base64 string and convert it back to an image. I haven't played with PowerApps in a while but it might be worth testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar solution to what you are looking for, you'd have to:

```
1- Create a custom API to route your images from the source you get them from (Example on article bellow is from camera to Blob)
2- Test your API locally in Azure Emulator
3- Publish API to Azure
4- Register the Custom API in PowerApps:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/register-custom-api
```

The full step by step guide can be found here: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-api-for-image-upload/ 
Let me know if this helped Alan.

Comment: Yeah I ended up pretty much doing the exact same thing. I created an API to get the images sent by Powerapps, and used it to send the image to BLOB storage.